# App to add furigana

Tags: discussion, furigana

I suppose I can add furigana manually in LibreOffice, and I know I can do it in HTML with CSS, but is there a free or low-cost program that can do it with sufficient accuracy that proofreading/correction won't take just as long as entering it all manually?

Prefer Mac/Linux/BSD/Solaris but can use Windows or IOS.  I have quite a bit of public-domain text that I want to print with furigana but I don't want to spend five months entering the kana.  I want to put it on *all* kanji because the audience is quite varied.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Unfortunately we don't handle requests of this type on our main site. Any automated approach is likely to need severe editing afterwards, my guess is that even professional publishers just add furigana by hand and where needed. You can try http://yomoyomo.jp/ and see if it helps.

Comment: I cannot talk about correctness, but there are many generators. [This one](http://furigana.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.cgi) seems to create simpler HTML code and LibreOffice documents.